# Converting a normal String to JSON in java

Tags: java, json, type-conversion

i've been searching a lot for a way to convert a normal String, not an Array, and i'm stuck in my code. I've programmed an API that return me the following json

```
[{
    "Id": "6d052279342d66d1ae4d4a84da0f98b80313277a3faeca4d7e822076c9dd4316",
    "Names": ["/elegant_bartik"],
    "Image": "alpine",
    "ImageID": "sha256:3fd9065eaf02feaf94d68376da52541925650b81698c53c6824d92ff63f98353",
    "Command": "/bin/sh",
    "Created": 1525954440,
    "Ports": [],
    "Labels": {},
    "State": "running",
    "Status": "Up About an hour",
    "HostConfig": {
        "NetworkMode": "default"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "430ff6d43b361b0a2f45046c575862ca4785216a0242e72d145c269f3ef326df",
                "EndpointID": "a7a2012d7841af6b5b76e24f57b13a5057252b511e8dbfb48e74aa1cc19e30b4",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    },
    "Mounts": []
}]
```

The problem is, I need to put it into an JSONObject, is there any function or sequence of functions that could do that? Or do I need to break the whole String?

I've tried JSONParse, Gson(from Google) and a lot more, but none of then works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The JSON you have posted is an array (denoted by `[]`) containing a single object (denoted by `{}`)

You will first need to parse the JSON into an array, for example (using GSON):

```
JsonArray arr = new Gson().fromJson(string, JsonArray.class)
```

And then you can access the first object in the array:

```
JsonElement ele = arr.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the json array string looks okay. you will have to read it as a jsonArray, then loop through each getting the jsonObjects.

```
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed); 
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's a JSONArray. You first need to get the root json array. Then you can get the first object from that.